# Diplay 0.20 instead 0.2 in BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have juste one question :)

> BigDecimal val = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.20);
>           System.out.println(a);

i want to store in `val` a value `0.20` and not `0.2`. 
What i can do ?

Comment: This is due to displaying, it is still stored as 0.20 (with a lot more decimals probably).

Answer (score 5):

When you want to control how a number is formatted, look at [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and particularly the concrete [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) subclass.

You can create a `DecimalFormat` either from a pattern, or just set the various aspects of it directly. You then ask it to format your `BigDecimal`, and it will give you the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's small example how to use `DecimalFormat` to meet your need

```
double d = 1.2345;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
System.out.println(df.format(d)); // will print 1.23
d = 3.400;
System.out.println(df.format(d)); // will print 3.40
d = 3.456;
System.out.println(df.format(d)); // will print 3.46

BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(0.20001);
System.out.println(df.format(b)); // will print 0.20
```

Comment: You don't even need to pass 0.20001, 0.2 will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store `0.20` instead of `0.2` in a variable, since they are the same values. You can, however, change the way the result is printed.

Your question makes me assume you're a beginner in Java programming. Rather than just take a plain answer, you should read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for an elaborate understanding of how this works.